# Angular - Array(20) difference [object, object]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am retrieving data over a service and I am getting the result as Array(20) if I check my browser. Well I will need the result as following:

How can I do it?

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

```
this.apiService.callSearchQuery(this.jsonDataSearch).subscribe(result => {  
    if (result[0]) {
       this.items = result[0];
       console.log(this.items)
    }
});
```

Comment: Please make the question more clear. What's the problem? What have you tried? How do you actually get the data?

Comment: Are you asking about the way developer tools in your browser present the data? Why is this tagged as Angular and TypeScript then? Maybe you're looking for `JSON.stringify`?